# How do I make the OpenDDS DCPSInfoRepo persistent?

Tags: data-distribution-service, opendds

I have been trying to find a solution where if the DCPSInfoRepo of OpenDDS is restarted, the existing publishers and subscribers do not reconnect. I found a way in the developer guide which says:

> The following directive:
> static PersistenceUpdater_Static_Service "-file info.pr -reset 1"
> will persist DCPSInfoRepo updates to local file info.pr. If a file by that name already exists,
> its contents will be erased. Used with the command-line option -r, the DCPSInfoRepo can be
> reincarnated to a prior state. When using persistence, start the DCPSInfoRepo process using
> a TCP fixed port number with the following command line option. This allows existing
> clients to reconnect to a restarted InfoRepo.

So I created a svc.conf file and gave it as an argument along with the flag -ORBSvcConf while starting DCPSInfoRepo. Unfortunately I get an error message saying that the PersistenceUpdater_Static_Service was not located. I have tried to search in the documents as well other places on the internet but have been unlucky so far.

Would appreciate if someone can help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `static PersistenceUpdaterSvc "-file info.pr"` in your svc.conf file.